# F# - Expected to be option but has a type

Tags: f#

I was trying to build a binary tree in F# but when I tried to test my code, I met the problem above.

Here is my code:

```
type TreeNode<'a> = { Key: int; Val: 'a }
type Tree<'a> =  { LT: Tree<'a> option; TreeNode: TreeNode<'a>; RT: Tree<'a> option; }

//insert a node according to Binary Tree operation
let rec insert (node: TreeNode<'a>) (tree: Tree<'a> option) =
    match tree with
    | None -> {LT = None; RT = None; TreeNode = node }
    | Some t when node.Key < t.TreeNode.Key -> insert node t.LT
    | Some t when node.Key > t.TreeNode.Key -> insert node t.RT

let t = seq { for i in 1 .. 10 -> { Key = i; Val = i } }|> Seq.fold (fun a i -> insert i a) None
```

Comment: On which line do you see the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out now... It should be like below:

```
type TreeNode<'a> = { Key: int; Val: 'a }
type Tree<'a> =  { TreeNode: TreeNode<'a>; RT: Tree<'a> option; LT: Tree<'a> option; }

//insert a node according to Binary Tree operation
let rec insert (node: TreeNode<'a>) (tree: Tree<'a> option) =
    match tree with
    | None -> {LT = None; RT = None; TreeNode = node }
    | Some t when node.Key < t.TreeNode.Key -> {TreeNode = t.TreeNode; LT = Some(insert node t.LT); RT = t.RT}
    | Some t when node.Key > t.TreeNode.Key -> {TreeNode = t.TreeNode; RT = Some(insert node t.RT); LT = t.LT}

let t = seq { for i in 1 .. 10-> { Key = i; Val = i } }|> Seq.fold (fun a i -> Some(insert i a)) None
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `insert` function takes `option<Tree<'T>>` but returns `Tree<'T>`. When performing the `fold`, you need to keep state of the same type - so if you want to use `None` to represent empty tree, the state needs to be optional type.

The way to fix this is to wrap the result of `insert` in `Some`:

```
let tree = 
  seq { for i in 1 .. 10 -> { Key = i; Val = i } }
  |> Seq.fold (fun a i -> Some(insert i a)) None
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.

But now the result shows:

val t : Tree<int> option = Some {TreeNode = {Key = 10;
                                             Val = 10;};
                                 RT = null;
                                 LT = null;}

Whereas I expected it to be a chain from 1 to 10..